# how to create a JSON file with c++ methods

Tags: c++, json, xml

We are doing a black box testing in our project,For that we wanted to use json and c++ and Jzon for parsing.can anybody show how to write a json file for c++ method and parse to get the node by using jzon ?

Comment: Instead of just asking question you should show some of your effort for better answer.

Comment: I am new to json and jzon.I know that json files can be parsed using jzon library.can you provide any document to get idea on the library calls ?

Answer (score 0):

To write Json object (Jzon::Node) to file you can use Jzon::Writer class.
There are three methods [writeStream](https://github.com/Zguy/Jzon/blob/91b09881bd35e4c55d6f7c31aeebe166d1653686/Jzon.h#L239),[writeString](https://github.com/Zguy/Jzon/blob/91b09881bd35e4c55d6f7c31aeebe166d1653686/Jzon.h#L240) and [writeFile](https://github.com/Zguy/Jzon/blob/91b09881bd35e4c55d6f7c31aeebe166d1653686/Jzon.h#L241). Based on target where you want to save your object you can you appropriate method. To save into file you should use writeFile.

You code should be like this.

```
std::string filename="some path and file name.json";
Jzon::Node node;
//fill your object
Jzon::Writer write;
write.writeFile(node,filename);
```